# Webapps on Chrome - not Chromium - with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, google-chrome, webapps

I've been trying to find some info on this, but I only got very confusing or old pages. I simply would like to know if I can use the webapps on my Chrome (version 29.0.1547.76) with Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the unity web apps, the simple answer is no. But you might be able to get the folders where the Chromium-based extensions are, and copy them to your Chrome profile folder. If you want more help, just ask. (I haven't tried this)

Comment: I mean apps like this one

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-webapps-gmail/

Comment: those are the sort of apps I mean. Do you want more help?

Comment: Actually, I gave up. Most of these apps are only cosmetic, and the benefits of chrome - namely pdf reader and flash - are way more useful than them...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings (button on the right) > Tools > Create Application Shortcuts...

I know that this works in Precise (12.04) and Trusty (14.04) so I assume that it works in the (now unsupported) 13.04.